# Solr full reindex appears to have failed on two nodes

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I attempted to perform a full Solr reindex for our Cassandra cluster this past weekend.  It seemed that two nodes were taking a lot longer than the other three, in fact they keep indexing for hours after the others were done.  Finally it seemed they had finished, at least in the web console they both said "no" for indexing field in the web console.

Unfortunately about an hour later one of those two nodes became completely unresponsive, and ultimately had to be restarted.

Today I'm looking at the nodes, and the 3 that didn't seem to have any problems all claim to have about 14.8 million docs or so, which is about what it should be.  However the two that were stuck, or took forever (including the one that ulimately became unresponsive) have only 9 and 7 million respectively.  That is a huge discrepancy which tells me that they didn't complete correctly.

So, to resolve the issue I have two questions:

1) Since this was a full reindex, are the changes that were implemented to the schema and hence the reason for the full index, good?  In other words is it only the indexing part that didn't finish, so can I just run a regular in place reindex to get everything back to the way it should be?

2) Assuming I don't have to run a full reindex, can I just run an in place reindex on the two nodes that are out of whack?  From a time perspective this would be ideal as I'd have to do it after hours anyway, and it would hopefully finish overnight.

Just wondering how to proceed, as I haven't had this issue in the past.

Comment: I should add, I just went through the system logs and verified that the reindexing did successfully complete on the 3 nodes that appeared correct, and I also verified that it did not complete on the 2 that appear out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your questions:

1) Yes, you can do a reload with in-place reindex by setting reindex=true, deleteAll=false.

2) Yes, you can run an in-place reindex on the failed nodes only by invoking a reload on each node and setting reindex=true, deleteAll=false,  distributed=false.

Have a look at: http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchReldCore.html

Anyway, it would be good to first understand why those nodes failed: that kind of behaviour looks like an out of memory error, but are there any exceptions in your logs?